# List Box with section headers and data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I am working on `windows Phone 8 app` ,need to achieve something like the below image looks like.

[image]

I have searched for this but did not get any help,please help me how to achieve this ?

Comment: Is it WPF or Windows Phone as grouping works different here and is _Header-1_ and _Header-2_ some property of your view model?

Comment: @dkozl Its for Windows PHone 8 application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a LongListSelector

LongListSelector which is actually an advanced ListBox that supports full data and UI virtualization, flat lists and grouped lists. It helps users to scroll through long lists of data. Basically a quick jump grid overlays the list when the user select one of the group headers after that when an item is selected from the grid the user is automatically redirected back to the long list at the selected point.

it also comes up with ways to manage headers and contents separately and efficiently.

Best [Link](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api) to take a start with

One [more](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth).

Enjoy :)

Comment: I have a doubt here, i need the complete XAML how it looks like, because i am confused where do i need to place all these can you please help me ?

Comment: and also i am using only GroupHeaderTemplate and ItemTemplate

Comment: okay , just check this one http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-longlistselector-control and http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/LongListSelector-Demo-45364cc9

Comment: can youplease check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21986760/binding-data-in-longlistselector

Answer (score 1):

You can use longlistSelector with grouping to achieve something like that.
[Here is a example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj244365%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there any simple tutorial, which have so that i can understand easily ?

Comment: GeekChamp has http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/the-new-longlistselector-control-in-windows-phone-8-sdk-in-depth