# Divide a listbox in multiple pages ( Visual Studio C# )

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to divide my listbox in pages instead of having to scroll to see the latest items in my listbox. (I'm a beginner and I don't know how to even start to do it).
[This is what I have currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsW4W.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List Box with section headers and data binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984065/list-box-with-section-headers-and-data-binding)

Comment: You should include some code to evaluate what you have tried. By the way you need listbox pagination.

Comment: If you would rather scroll through pages you can set MultiColumn = true to see if that comes closer to what you want..

Comment: @ Aïssa Kahloul. Is your project a Windows Forms App (.NET Framework) or a WPF App (.NET Framework)? If it is a wpf project, you could try to bind the view to achieve this function.